# warning C4800: 'BOOL' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

When I compile the below code snippet code in Visual studio 2008, I get this warning.

```
BOOL
CPlan::getStandardPlan() const
{
    return m_standardPlan;
}


bool m_bStandardPlan;

if(plan!=NULL)
{
    // Assign the values to the Cola object
    poCola->m_lPlanId           = plan->getPlanId();
    poCola->m_lPlanElementId        = plan->getPlanElementId();
    poCola->m_lPlanElementBaseId        = plan->getPlanElementBaseId();
    poCola->m_bStandardPlan         = plan->getStandardPlan(); //C4800

    return 1;
}
```

I referred the following links,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

[Forcing value to boolean: (bool) makes warning, !! doesnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439494/forcing-value-to-boolean-bool-makes-warning-doesnt)

[Warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919650/warning-c4800-int-forcing-value-to-bool-true-or-false-performance-warn)

I'm not sure how to fix this warnings.

Comment: Why don't you use `bool` instead of `BOOL` as a return value in the first place?

Comment: @Henrik if user3360310 has not adopted Microsoft's "prefix-everything-with-C" notation, `CPlan` looks much like a class from some MS library, so the signature cannot be changed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`BOOL` is a typedef for `int` somewhere in WinAPI. WinAPI is a C API, so they can't use C++'s `bool`. If you can't get rid of it by returning a `bool` from the function, e.g. because you don't maintain the function, then you can use an explicit check against zero to get rid of the warning:

```
poCola->m_bStandardPlan = (plan->getStandardPlan() != 0);
```

Another consideration would be to add a function that encapsulates the check:

```
bool getStandardPlan(CPlan const& plan) {
  return plan->getStandardPlan() != 0;
}
```

and then

```
poCola->m_bStandardPlan = getStandardPlan(plan);
```

Comment: [it's simpler to use `poCola->m_bStandardPlan = !!plan`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/206106/995714)

Answer (score 10):

`getStandardPlan()` returns a `BOOL` which actually is a typedef of an `int` (0 is interpeted as `false` and all other values as `true`). I usually solve this issue with the ternary operator.

```
poCola->m_bStandardPlan = plan->getStandardPlan() ? true : false;
```

Comment: Thank you @k4rlsson. I now understand why compiler throwed this warning.